# Computer Science regarding ERD

Tags: database, computer-science, erd, information-schema

I am trying to work on this problem but i am having some issues with it I was wondering if somebody would be able to assist me with this problem.
[image]

Comment: Having issues with this problem please click the image description to see picture

Comment: Please share your rough work first, then we can guide you.